# OnInitDialog: reset dialog content

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a PropertySheet containing 6 PropertyPages. During OnInitDialog of each page, a setting structure assigns initial values to the dialog controls.

However at some point, I want to change my setting structure and each dialog must show newly assigned values for each control it has. Like resseting every dialog.

To achive this, I tried removing and adding all 6 pages but it didn't work. How can I reset every dialog control without manually setting new values to controls.

If I can call OnInitDialog function it would work. However I cannot call OnInitDialog twice.

Comment: Not enough info... Maybe [UpdateData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww.aspx).

Comment: The only way to call InitDialog is to close and re-open the dialog box. Alternatively, (not very sure if this will work for MFC-PropertyPages), you could try sending a `WM_INITDIALOG` message to each property page.

Comment: Just move initialization to separate function in each page and call it manually when you need to reset values. That's it

Comment: Would [CPropertyPage::OnSetActive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zd196y3(v=vs.120).aspx) provide you the necessary event to update your data?